# "add to cart" links css class "ajax_add_to_cart" doesn't show in woocommerce in widget sidebar

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

I create woocmmerce widget that will create loop by product category. Product loops result should as much as same woocommerce default content-product.php file. And everything is fine within loop ( attributes, link etc ) except `css class`. I can't figure out actually where i messed up, **but i guess the main problem is within `$defaults` variable or in `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args` filter.** Please someone help me.

here is my code -

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( !empty( $title )) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
    }
    $defaults = array(
        'cat' => '',
        'posts' => '-1',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'thumbs' => '',
        'hidden_p' => '',
        'oos_p' => '',
    );
    if (empty($instance['posts'])) {
        $instance['posts'] = $defaults['posts'];
    }

    if (empty($instance['orderby'])) {
        $instance['orderby'] = $defaults['orderby'];
    }

    if (empty($instance['order'])) {
        $instance['order'] = $defaults['order'];
    }

    ?>

    <ul class="products productsbycat_list productsbycat_<?php echo $instance['cat']; ?> column-4">
        <?php
        $arggs = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => $instance['posts'],
            'product_cat' => $instance['cat'],
            'orderby' => $instance['orderby'],
            'order' => $instance['order'],
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($arggs);
        $show_hidden = ($instance['hidden_p'] == '1') ? true : false;
        $show_oos = ($instance['oos_p'] == '1') ? true : false;

        while ($loop->have_posts()):
            $loop->the_post();
            global $product;
            $show_hidden_product = true;
            $show_oos_product = true;

            if ( $show_hidden ) {
                if ( ! $product->is_visible()) {
                    $show_hidden_product = true;
                }
            } else {
                if ( ! $product->is_visible()) {
                    $show_hidden_product = false;
                }
            }

            if ( $show_oos ) {
                if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
                    $show_oos_product = true;
                }
            } else {
                if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
                    $show_oos_product = false;
                }
            }

            $output = '';
            if ($show_hidden_product && $show_oos_product) {
                $output .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', wc_get_product_class( '', $product ) ) ) . '"><div class="global_product_wrapper">';

                $output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink($loop->post->ID).'" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link" title="'.esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID).'">';



                $image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', 'woocommerce_thumbnail' );

                $output .= $product ? $product->get_image( $image_size ) : '';
                $output .= '</a>';

                $output .= '<div class="title-and-price">';

                $output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink($loop->post->ID).'" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link" title="'.esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID).'">';
                $output .= '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                $output .= '</a>';

                if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) :
                    $output .= '<span class="price">' . $price_html . '</span>';
                endif;

                $output .= '</div>';

                $output .= '<div class="custom_add_to_cart_wrapper">';
                        if ( $product ) {
                            $defaults = array(
                                'quantity'   => 1,
                                'class'      => implode(
                                    ' ',
                                    array_filter(
                                        array(
                                            'button',
                                            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
                                            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                                            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),
                                'attributes' => array(
                                    'data-product_id'  => $product->get_id(),
                                    'data-product_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
                                    'aria-label'       => $product->add_to_cart_description(),
                                    'rel'              => 'nofollow',
                                ),
                            );

                            $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ), $product );

                            if ( isset( $args['attributes']['aria-label'] ) ) {
                                $args['attributes']['aria-label'] = wp_strip_all_tags( $args['attributes']['aria-label'] );
                            }

                            $output .= apply_filters(
                                'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
                                sprintf(
                                    '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
                                    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                                    esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
                                    esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
                                    isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
                                    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
                                ),
                                $product,
                                $args
                            );
                        }
                $output .= '<div>';

                $output .= '</div></li>';
            }
            echo $output;

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php

echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

My themes shop page add to cart class -

[image: woocommerce shop page css class]

But in my widget's sidebar show -

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i solved it myself. Hope someone will get benefit form this answer. I merge `$default` variables all array (`quantity`, `class`, `attributes`) directly into link. I changed whole block of `if ( $product ) {}`.

```
if ( $product ) {
    $output .= sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="1" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr(
        implode(
            ' ',
            array_filter(
                array(
                    'button', 'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
                    $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                    $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    wc_implode_html_attributes(
        array(
            'data-product_id'  => $product->get_id(),
            'data-product_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
            'aria-label'       => $product->add_to_cart_description(),
            'rel'              => 'nofollow',
        )
    ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    );
}
```